# How does PHP insert datetime into bigQuery?

Tags: php, datetime, google-bigquery

Inserting a datetime into BigQuery is throwing an error:

> invalid: no such field

> 2021-01-09 08:17:18.000000

Which is created with something like this:

> $datetime_for_BigQuery = date('Y-m-d H:i:s.u', null);

What **date format** would bigQuery accept, or have I misunderstood this error?

Comment: What's the result of that 3rd bit of code? Doesn't actually look like that would run. Are you trying to get the current timestamp? You'd want to time `time()`...

Comment: @FluxCoder your absolutely right, the code used is corrected above, and the change copied out below:  

`$datetime_for_BigQuery = date('Y-m-d H:i:s.u\Z', null);`

Comment: The answer was that i'm an idiot and was injecting the dict into BigQuery wrong.
Also, the format was slightly off. code corrected above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was creating the array incorrectly. This is the way that's worked:

```
$data = [
 "Full_Name" => "Febtestn5",
 "Email" => "FebTes2@mctestie.com",
 "dateCreated" => $new_date
];

$insertResponse = $table->insertRows([
    ['data' => $data],
]);
```